# Help with coding this table

Tags: tables, longtable, code

I have this table in word that I want to code to overleaf. I tried one, but the sentences were too long and it looked weird. I want it to be as long as the text is or maybe slightly less but not centred. I have attached the image, any solutions? [image: Table to code to overleaf]

I tried this code:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{430pt}{|c|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Paragraph \#} & \textbf{Description:} \\
\hline
1 & \pbox{20cm}{\emph{Rhetorical questions/Introduction} \\ 
    Why get someone who only \emph{pretends} to be a doctor when you 
    could get a real one? \\ \emph{Relate to audience} \\ Some more sentence
    here.} \\ 

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

But didn't work well.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

Observe the use of `\par` directives to force line breaks within a given column. Do also note that the `X` column type permits automatic linebreaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Paragraph \#} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
1 & \emph{Rhetorical questions\slash Introduction} \par
    Why get someone who only \emph{pretends} to be a doctor when you 
    could get a real one? \par 
    \emph{Relate to audience} \par 
    Some more sentences here. \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}|p{6cm}}\hline
SOLUTION&PROTOCOL\\hline
Alkline lysis agent&25mM NAOH 0.2 mM EDTA  pH[12]\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
% You can add remaining lines before end tabular